# How to set global variables and global functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `language.js`，I have:

```
function setCookie(cookie) {
  var Days = 30; //this cookie will keep 30 days 
  var exp = new Date(); //new Date("December 31, 9998");
  exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + Days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  document.cookie = cookie + ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
}

function setLanguage(lang) {
  setCookie("lang=" + lang + "; path=/;");
  translate(lang);
}
```

later on:

```
switch (getCookieVal("lang")) {
  case "en":
    setLanguage("en");
    break
  case "zh":
    setLanguage("zh");
    break
  default:
    setLanguage(systemLang);
}
```

this makes `console.log(getCookieVal("lang"));` print out `zh`. In a word, it works, however, if I use `console.log(getCookieVal("lang"))` in another file named `data.js` it doesn't work.

I really need to use `getCookieVal("lang")` to determine which variable to be used according to the cookie language.

Here is the full code:

```
var dict = {};
var systemLang = navigator.language.toLowerCase().slice(0, 2);
```

I already take the function out of wrapper, so now should be global function, but it is still not defined. To make question simple. You see, I make `systemLang` as global variable, however I use `console.log(systemLang)` in other `.js` file. It is not defined.

Comment: *"...it not working..."* Not working how? What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: can i use getCookieVal("lang") in another js file??? i am new to Java script. i do not know how to make function global

Comment: *"can i use getCookieVal("lang") in another js file?"* Yes if it is included in the page.

Comment: Yes, you can. (See my answer.) But please do look in the web console for errors.

Comment: it says getCookieVal is not defined

Comment: That suggests my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one file 
 localStorage.setItem('TheVariableNameYouWant',TheValueofTheVariableYouWant);

In another file 
localStorage.getItem('TheVariableNameYouWant')

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like these functions are in some kind of wrapper, like a jQuery `ready` callback:

```
$(function() {
    function setCookie(cookie) {
        // ...
    }
    function setLanguage(lang) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

or a scoping IIFE:

```
(function() {
    function setCookie(cookie) {
        // ...
    }
    function setLanguage(lang) {
        // ...
    }
})();
```

That means they're not global. If you want them to be global, be sure they're declared at the top level, not inside anything:

```
function setCookie(cookie) {
    // ...
}
function setLanguage(lang) {
    // ...
}
```

JavaScript doesn't pay any attention to what file the function is in (unless you use modules, but I don't think you are), all globals are truly global, regardless of the file.

---

I should note that using globals isn't generally best practice. The global namespace on browsers is **very** crowded. Instead, look at the various module bundlers and such.

Comment: i upload full code... can you give me a way to call the console.log(getCookieVal("lang")) in another Js file???  i need to use getCookieVal(getCookieVal("lang")) to know which language is the page and change variable according to the lang in cookie

Comment: @12345GG - As I said above, move the functions out of the function wrapper they're in.